# paypal integration in rails using js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment-processing, paypal-buttons

So guys, I am trying to get custom payments using js (paypal buttons) in a multivendor site(built using rails).the price for the listing is present in @listing.price . I have to implement this price as the checkout price in paypal (using paypal buttons if possible).

`<script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({
            price = document.getElementById('price');
            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: 'price'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },`

```
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');


</script>
```

this code shows the correct value(price of the listing)

```
<%= @listing.price %>
```

STill something im missing.could you help..if possible Is THERE any other way for multivendor payment processing in rails (other than stripe...as outside US)

Comment: Please refine your question,what is missing? What is your problem? Because you say it's displaying the right price. Post an error message, if you have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue from what I see is that you aren't attempting to pass the price  through your `<div id="price">`..

To pass the `<%= @listing.price %>` to Javascript, try setting a data attribute on the  `<div id="price">` as such:  `<div id="price" data-price="<%= @listing.price %>">`. Then you should be able to receive it in javascript by `price.dataset.price`. `#dataset` refers to all data attributes that are on a `div` and `#price` is the arbitrary name you give the data-attribute.